# expression in typeid is evaluated twice in runtime?

Tags: c++, typeid

Note that expression in typeid operator would be evaluated in runtime if it is a lvalue of a type with virtual member.

I have a trivial  `Base` class as follows

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const std::string &s):sval(s){}
    virtual ~Base()=default; 
private:
    std::string sval;
};
```

and a trivial function to return a lvalue of Base as follows:

```
Base& ChangeBase(Base &b)
{
    std::cout<<"Called"<<std::endl;
    return b;
}
```

When I wrote following codes to examine typeid operator:

```
int main()
{

    Base b("Dream");
    typeid (ChangeBase(b));
    return 0;
}
```

I got following output:

```
Called
Called
```

It indicated that function `ChangeBase` was called twice, so did it mean that expression in typeid would be evaluated twice in runtime (if need to evaluate in runtime)? If yes, why?

I'm using gcc 4.9.3

Comment: Fyi, clang 3.8 prints `Called` *once*.

Comment: Gcc6.1.0 prints once too.

Comment: Not reproduced with g++ (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34e4906ceb99affa)

Comment: gcc 4.8.3 prints once.

Comment: @skypjack If passed a glvalue expression of polymorphic type said expression is evaluated at runtime. OP is correct at that.

Comment: @songyuanyao I'm using gcc 4.9.3

Comment: @sigy Right. I've just seen the snippets in the question. Misread the definition of `Base` and misunderstood the intention of the OP. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC first check value for being null then evaluated it again and only after that calls typeid.

Assembly: https://godbolt.org/g/SoLFYq

```
    lea     rax, [rbp-64]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    ChangeBase(Base&)
    test    rax, rax
    je      .L8
    lea     rax, [rbp-64]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    ChangeBase(Base&)
...
.L8:
    call    __cxa_bad_typeid
```

Comment: Thanks. Any insight on why this behavior is not in gcc 4.8.3 and 6.1?